# Bending a bar magnet at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

How can one find the expression for Magnetic moment of a magnet bent in the ratio m:n at an angle "a" (in radian).
Given that the old magnetic moment (before bending) is "M" with length "l".
 It's pictorial representation seems something like this:
[image]

P.S. Even a small hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic moment of a bar magnet is directly proportional to its length.

The magnetic moments of the white and red parts are two separate vectors that we need to sum to find the net moment.

The length of the white part is $(\frac{m}{m+n})l$ and for the red part it's $(\frac{n}{m+n})l$.

So,$$\frac{M_{red}}{M}=\frac{(\frac{m}{m+n})l}{l}$$

$$M_{red}=(\frac{m}{m+n})M$$and$$M_{white}=(\frac{n}{m+n})M$$

As vectors, these moments point along the length of each bar segment, like so (red is north)
[image]

Since you know the magnitudes of the two vectors and the angles between them, you can find the resultant.